# PHP Email to customer

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

I have a problem with some programming. When a customer orders a table at a cafe on the cafe's website, the owner of the cafe could go in and approve or reject the order. Then the customer who ordered board must receive an email which says that the email is accepted or rejected.

```
<?php

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results='utf8&#8242;");

function escapeAddr($addr) {
    $check = preg_match('/(.*)<(.*)>/', $addr, $a);
    if ($check) $addr = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($a[1]).'?= <'.$a[2].'>';
    return $addr;
}
function mail_utf8($to, $subject='no subject', $message='', $from='', $cc='', $bcc='') {
$to = $email;
$subject = "subject";
$message = "message" ;
$from = escapeAddr($from);
$header = 'From: '.$from.PHP_EOL
            . 'Return-Path: '.$from.PHP_EOL
            . 'Reply-To: '.$from.PHP_EOL
            . 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.PHP_EOL
            . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8'.PHP_EOL
            . 'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion().PHP_EOL
            . 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'.PHP_EOL;
    if ($cc!='') $header .= 'Cc: '.escapeAddr($cc).PHP_EOL;
    if ($bcc!='') $header .= 'Bcc: '.escapeAddr($bcc).PHP_EOL;
    $header .= PHP_EOL;
    return mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $header);
}

$g_id = ( isset( $_GET['id']) && is_numeric( $_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : FALSE);
if( !$g_id) {
    echo 'Error'; // ID not currect
}
else {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM $tbl_name WHERE id=$g_id");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $email = $row['email'];

    if( mail_utf8($email, 'Table', 'message', 'no-reply@email.com')) {
        echo 'Accepted'; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Error';
    }
}
?>
```

The owner must, of course, log in to be able to approve or reject the order.
Since it is a form you press to reject or approve, but a `<a href` link, I have used the path `accept.php?Id=`.

The email have to be sended to the email that's matches the order.

Comment: your question is not clear
please edit and put out a clear question in order to receive support

Comment: The question is:

Have can i get this to work.
- it dosen't work, if i click on the accept link.

The customer don't get a email, if the owner accept og reject the order.

Please check the code for errors.
Maybe something don't have to be there, maybe I miss something.
I don't know.

Comment: **Spam** if you do this your emails maybe always go in spam/junk section because this is normally looks spam remember all these really your subscriber and to complete this task use constant contact or SSL

Comment: Spam or not.
- I just have to get this to work.

But I can't find the error.

Answer (score 1):

in some servers,depend on settings, php mailer not work! maybe you need SMTP class to send mail.

Answer (score 0):

At first, the Html-Character in your second Mysql-Query has not to be there. Replace it with a '
And second you could try to strip the Content-Transfer-Encoding from the mail-header.
Third, but trivial reason: is $tbl_name set? Are you sure, that the adress in the $from-variable has the correct format for the regular expression?